# How to set a vector as the y-axis with pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow, yaxis

I would like to set a y-axis with pcolor, such as the y-axis would be depth. in this example, I would like to set the vector  z as the y-axis, how can I do that?
this is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
z=np.arange(1,90,2)
mrectest = np.random.rand(45, 15)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.1)

im = ax.pcolor(mrectest,vmin = 0.1, vmax = 800, norm = LogNorm(),cmap= 'jet')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator())  # <- Why? See above.
#ax.invert_yaxis()
#cbar.set_ticks(cbar.ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().tick_values(0.01, 1000))
plt.savefig('mrec_exp_28_02'+'.png',bbox_inches = "tight", format='png', dpi=1000)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: Consider that `ax.pcolor(x,y,z)` receives x, y, and z data.

Comment: I gave a matrix, mrectest(45,15), that would be my x,y? or my z values? the plot I did is just like I need, the only think is that the y -labels are just the numbers of lines in the matrix (0-45) and I would like to be the vector z...

Comment: `mrectest` would be `z`. `x, y` would be the vectors you want to provide.